# [NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Bad file descriptor - Crashes app on startup

Tags: ios, crash, nsfilehandle

I'm using GTMLogger and have the following piece of code that seems to be crashing since moving to iOS5.1 . The weird thing i can't seem to reproduce it, but i know its happening to many users, so I'm not sure how to track it.

`[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Bad file descriptor`

I could just try/catch it but its not a solution as much as a workaround.

This is the suspicious part:

```cpp
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:logFilePath];
if (file) 
{
    unsigned long long maxFileOffset = [file seekToEndOfFile];
    if (maxFileOffset > kDebugFileMaxSize)
    {
        // read file, trunicate, save, reopen
        [file seekToFileOffset:maxFileOffset - kDebugFileMaxSize];
        NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[file readDataToEndOfFile]];
        [file seekToFileOffset:0];
        [file writeData:data];
        [file truncateFileAtOffset:kDebugFileMaxSize];
        [file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
}
else 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:logFilePath];
}
```

Anyone ever got something like that ?

Comment: Hi, I am also getting this error. Why it s coming & How did you solved it? Please share.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually just got rid of GTMLogger and moved to some other logger, thanks for anyone who might've read this :)

Comment: Are you saying that GTMLogger was causing your unrelated NSFileHandle code to crash?

Comment: That does seem weird, but indeed removing GTMLogger at the time solved the problem.